# Calculate left days and filter by them?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I want to filter my custom query by compare server (SQL) time and timestamp from the database ACF datepicker in my case

I have a query here:

```
$wpdb->get_results('SELECT goodies.ID, meta1.meta_value AS promotion_duration_date FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts AS goodies
    LEFT JOIN '. $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta meta1 ON meta1.post_id = goodies.ID AND meta1.meta_key = "promotion_duration_date"
    WHERE goodies.post_type = "goodies" and goodies.post_status = "publish" 
    ORDER BY goodies.ID
    ');
```

My goal is to calculate how many days are left between the `promotion_duration_date` variable and server time, and if is that number less than on example 10, run query?

Answer (score 0):

If the meta_value is a datetime field you could use the following snippet:

```
<?php
$wpdb->get_results('SELECT goodies.ID, meta1.meta_value AS promotion_duration_date, DATEDIFF(day, meta1.meta_value, NOW()) as daysleft FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts AS goodies
    LEFT JOIN '. $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta meta1 ON meta1.post_id = goodies.ID AND meta1.meta_key = "promotion_duration_date"
    WHERE goodies.post_type = "goodies" and goodies.post_status = "publish" 
    ORDER BY goodies.ID
    ');
```

If is not datetime you have to convert the value first:

```
<?php
$wpdb->get_results('SELECT goodies.ID, meta1.meta_value AS promotion_duration_date, DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT(meta1.meta_value, DATE), NOW()) as daysleft FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts AS goodies
    LEFT JOIN '. $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta meta1 ON meta1.post_id = goodies.ID AND meta1.meta_key = "promotion_duration_date"
    WHERE goodies.post_type = "goodies" and goodies.post_status = "publish" 
    ORDER BY goodies.ID
    ');
```

Comment: The array is now 0? Is format important?

Comment: what is the format in the meta_value field?